# ignoring space while reading a csv file using awk

Tags: csv, awk, space

I am pretty novice in shell scripting and seek advise on sending the following data by an email

#### Data in tb.csv file

```
09,01,14-Jan-2016 02:39:27,14-Jan-2016 02:40:25,14-Jan-2016 04:54:34,14-Jan-2016 07:54:54,,,01/16/2016
10,01,15-Jan-2016 02:38:45,15-Jan-2016 02:40:28,15-Jan-2016 03:50:50,15-Jan-2016 06:21:09,,,01/17/2016
11,01,,,,,,,01/19/2016
12,01,,,,,,,01/21/2016
13,01,,,,,,,01/23/2016
```

#### Script made

I have identified to store each value in the tb.csv file,as seperate variable  by the following

```
awk -F, 'NR==18 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' tb.csv | read ksk1 ksk2 ksk3 ksk4 ksk5 ksk6 ksk7 ksk8 ksk9
```

it is reading each value of line 18 and storing it in variable ksk(1 to 9)

#### Result expected

1. the variable ksk should hold the entire value `"14-Jan-2016 02:40:25"`, but `14-Jan-2016` is taking a different variable and
   `02:40:25` as other , it seems space is the issue - expecting  awk
   should ignore the space and consider the value in one variable
2. for data `11,01,,,,,,,01/19/2016` , in middle there are blank awk
   ignores the blank and assign value `01/19/2016` as 3rd `ksk` varibale -
   expecting   the blank values are holded as  seperate variable and
   the 9th variable is assigned the value  `01/19/2016`

Comment: You should read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 -- `some command | read var1 var2` will *not* keep the values in those variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can output the fields by awk with comma as delimiter, and set `IFS=","`  by reading:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{..yourcodes}'|IFS="," read...
```

Answer (score 0):

The awk part is doing everything you want, it's the shell afterwards that's not doing what you want with the awk output.

If you're using bash:

```
$ IFS=, read -ra ksk < <(awk 'NR==2' file)
$ for (( i=0; i<${#ksk[@]}; i++ )); do printf "ksk[%d]:\"%s\"\n" "$i" "${ksk[i]}"; done
ksk[0]:"10"
ksk[1]:"01"
ksk[2]:"15-Jan-2016 02:38:45"
ksk[3]:"15-Jan-2016 02:40:28"
ksk[4]:"15-Jan-2016 03:50:50"
ksk[5]:"15-Jan-2016 06:21:09"
ksk[6]:""
ksk[7]:""
ksk[8]:"01/17/2016"

$ IFS=, read -ra ksk < <(awk 'NR==3' file)
$ for (( i=0; i<${#ksk[@]}; i++ )); do printf "ksk[%d]:\"%s\"\n" "$i" "${ksk[i]}"; done
ksk[0]:"11"
ksk[1]:"01"
ksk[2]:""
ksk[3]:""
ksk[4]:""
ksk[5]:""
ksk[6]:""
ksk[7]:""
ksk[8]:"01/19/2016"
```

also google bash `mapfile` and `readarray` to see if they'd be useful to you.